# Why n log(n) has higher dominance than n?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Consider an example,
if n=4

n log(n)=4 * log (4) =2.408

n=4

Then how
n log(n)> n   ???

Comment: Because it's all about asymptotics. Look at the definition for the landau-notation (and try to fill in your example)!

Comment: Now try with n 4 000 000 000

Comment: Note that `log` depends on the base. You are using base 10, i.e. `log(4, 10)`, and `log(n, b) < 1` if `n` is smaller than the base `b`, but obviously this is not the norm.

Comment: In Big-O notation the base does not matter.

Comment: @tobias_k please see my answer - I explain your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Big O notations assume that n is large. n=4 is irrelevant to the complexity analysis.

In the general case, if you look at the ratio between both : `n.log(n) / n = log(n)` provided that n>0.

When n becomes large, this ratio tends to infinity, meaning that `n.log(n)` takes "infinitely" more time than `n`, and thus `n.log(n)` dominates `n`.

Comment: I'd be very interested to know what how I earned a down vote. :)

Comment: [tag:Big-O] doesn't assume anything.

Comment: Well that's not what I was taught in math class. :) Big O, and Landau's notation in general is asymptotic, thus is relevant when n tends to infinity : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: So you were missleaded. BigO is a set of functions which asymptotically don't grow faster then a certain function,.

Comment: Considering their growth when their main parameter, here n, tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

[big-o](/questions/tagged/big-o) describes how fast functions grow asymphotically. `nlogn` grows faster than `n` so in your notation, `O(nlogn) > O(n)`, however it's not a proper notation.

Actually `O(nlogn)` is a set as well as `O(n)` is. There is also a relation between them:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Just for clarification needed according to comments: all logarithms grow same fast according to [big-o](/questions/tagged/big-o):

[image]